# Smooth Brush is making my model less smooth while sculpting

Tags: sculpting, smooth, brushes

I am sculpting a human head at the moment and haven't had any issues so far with smoothing out certain parts of the model until very recently.

I already checked on the falloff of the brush and the direction (both are okay). Additionally, it isn't happening throughout the model, only in certain areas. I used the simplify brush here and there to add more geometry but it still isn't working.

Take a look at these screenshots to see the issue:
[image: rough smooth brush]
[image: second video]

I tried turning on dynamic topology with no luck.

Comment: Please be more explicit.. by 'Issues with smoothing'.. do you mean the smoothing brush isn't working?

Comment: hey robin, 
sorry for the lack of explanation. It may have to do explicitly with my model, but as you can see in the gif i linked, the brush almost roughens the model out when used. It worked perfectly fine when i was sculpting earlier.

Comment: Please don't use links to images. You can load them directly into your question so that they are immediately visible. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.

Comment: just edited my original post with a gif, sorry about that

Comment: look at the second gif, as i drag the brush around the entire model, only some parts are getting that type of "roughness" applied to it